# Getting SecurityException when trying to install appWidget in HomeScreen

Tags: android

am having a little trouble here. i don't know why i am getting a SecurityException, when trying to install my AppWidget on the home screen?. i don't know what will help to solve this but here is the simplified logcat output and my Android Manifest for starters:

```
11-30 18:02:16.454: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE cmp=com.MuchachaApps.WeatherViewer/.WeatherForecastConfigure (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{44e58dc8 287:android.process.acore/10001} (pid=287, uid=10001) requires null
11-30 18:02:16.454: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atandroid.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atandroid.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atandroid.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1214)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atandroid.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atandroid.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atcom.android.launcher.Launcher.startActivityForResult(Launcher.java:969)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atcom.android.launcher.Launcher.addAppWidget(Launcher.java:1148)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atcom.android.launcher.Launcher.onActivityResult(Launcher.java:379)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atandroid.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3828)
113018:02:16.454:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):atandroid.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3325)
11-30 18:02:16.454: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):... 11 more
```

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.MuchaaApps.WeatherViewer"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service android:name= "weatherForecast"></service>

<activity android:name=".WeatherForecastConfigure" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

<receiver android:name="WeatherWidgetProvider" android:label="Weather Forecast">
     <intent-filter> 
       <action android:name= "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
     </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.MuchaaApps.WeatherViewer.WEATHER_UPDATE"></action>
       </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
             android:resource="@xml/weather_appwidget_info"></meta-data>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

if you need any other information, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: anybody come across this before?..  please..

Comment: please any help.. been on this for some time now

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a configuration Activity that's supposed to come up when you add the widget to the launcher? If so, you need to add an `APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE` action to your intent-filter. If not, you need to remove the `android:configure` attribute from your appwidget-provider XML.

Having one but not the other is the problem.